# Can't continue code execution when application in separate thread crashes

Tags: c#, process, .net-core

I'm dealing with executing some other application that is highly unstable, and crushes a lot.

Here is my current setup, execution itself happening in T:

```
    var threadEndEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    var executionThread = new Thread(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await T();
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {
                    //deal with exceptions...
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    threadEndEvent.Set();
                    }
                }
```

I have Timer running on timeout:

```
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
        var result = Task.Run(() => executionThread.Abort()).Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        //log if aborting was succesful and other info...
        threadEndEvent.Set();
        }
```

After that I do this:

```
    executionThread.Start();
    threadEndEvent.Wait(timeoutSpan)
```

Eventually, one of two things happens: either thread finishes, or, after timeout, it attempts to abort it, logs everything that happened and moves on.

This seems to be working fine for most cases, however when I launch some other application and it crashes, displaying standard error like

> "exe stopped working, Windows can check online for the solution to the
>   problem"

aborting never happens, and everything hangs up.

I start that application in T this way:

```
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                //Specify path to exe, arguments, etc...
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

I'm aware that `WaitForExit` is thread blocking, however it is being executed in separate thread `executionThread`, so I'm not sure why execution hangs up.

What am I missing here? How do I make it so that it moves on after timeout no matter what happens?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is it your thread that crashes sometimes or is it an external application that you are launching from within that thread? It sounds more like you are launching an application. I am not sure how killing the thread would kill the external application, even after a timeout. Can you explain a little more or show a sample of your thread code/application launch?

Comment: @pstrjds updated question, i'm not trying to kill external application, I just need for my code to not hang up and move on if crash happened.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and breaking when this problem occurs? I am wondering if it might be locked up in the one of your output event handlers. This is a little bit of a wild guess, but `Process.WaitForExit` should return when the application crashes __but__ it will wait for any output redirection handlers to finish. I would think that your thread abort code would still fire and kill that thread, but it is possible that there is an asynchronous read operation that is stuck when the application crashes.

Comment: @pstrjds Weirdly enough, judging by logs, timer.Elapsed event never fires to begin with - everything seems to be stuck. Debugging is problematic right now, but I'll update the question once I'll be able to do it.

Comment: Based on what you described as happening, I am totally thrown off unless you have something else that is blocking your main thread. You do have a `Wait` call on that event, but you have a timeout, so I would expect the code to continue even if the timer didn't fire and abort the thread and set the event handle. You should still move on past that event handle. I suspect something else is going on _OR_ is it your application that crashed and popped up that dialog? Have you set  unhandled exception [handlers](https://stackify.com/catch-unhandled-exceptions-csharp/) in _your_ app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually found the solution. Unfortunately, debugger doesn't work properly so details are going to be very vague.

Once I started digging deeper, I found that `T` works like this:

```
var executingThread = new Thread(()=>{
//process code mentioned in question...
});
executingThread.Start();
executingThread.Join();
```

Not sure why it is that way, I'm dealing with undocumented legacy code.

Anyway, once I removed the extra thread code, exceptions are getting caught correctly and nothing hangs up.

Not sure why exactly creating extra thread makes exceptions uncatchable(never saw that problem when this code ran on .NET Framework), but if you are experiencing similar problem this may be a solution.